# Systemd service not working during system boot up

Tags: systemd, manjaro

So I wrote a systemd service file for *Manjaro Linux* to run two shell commands to set some kernel parameters at runtime to enable custom power saving actions.

BTW: This was a tip by a german computer magazine.
Originally I should place the shell commands in the `/etc/rc.local` file but I want to make it with a systemd service.
Because `rc.local` is considered as deprecated and I want to learn something new.

Below you see my service file saved as `/etc/systemd/system/power-savings.service`.
Because there are two `ExecStart` directives I have chosen `Type=oneshot`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable custom power saving actions provided by c't magazine
# Quelle(n):  c't 25/2016, S. 77
#             c't 26/2016, S. 12

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# SATA Link Power Management aktivieren
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'for I in /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/link_power_management_policy; do echo min_power > $I; done'
# Energieverwaltung für den Audiocodec aktivieren
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I verified the service file with:

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/power-savings.service
```

Then I reloaded the daemon with:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

I enabled it with:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable power-savings.service
```

Then I have run the service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl start power-savings.service
```

And it worked!
The kernel parameters have been set.

But then, after rebooting my system the service seems not to have any effect.
Although, the service status said success...

```
$ systemctl status power-savings.service

Process: 412 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 404 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c for I in /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/link_power_management_policy; do echo min_power > $I; done (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 412 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

But the kernel parameter were not set.
So my service works during a user session, only.
Unfortunately not during system boot up as it was intended to work.

Is there something I might have missed?
Do I need some of those `After` or `Require` directives?
How am I able to debug what really happens with the `ExecStart` directives?

Answer (score 1):

Doing further research on my problem I found an interesting statement from the Arch Linux community.
In [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164580) user *calzon65* is trying to do something similar as I do.

The discussion redirected me to [an article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Temporary_files) about `tmpfiles.d` which could be a possible solution for writing values into files instead of using pipes or redirects.
However this article has an interesting **note**:

> This method may not work to set options in `/sys` since the *systemd-tmpfiles-setup* service may run before the appropriate device modules is loaded.

What our projects have in common is that we both indeed try to write to `/sys/...` during system boot up.
This fact is probably the answer to the question why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in your own answer, the most correct way I know of to solve your problem is to figure out at what stage in systemd's boot ordering the `/sys` modules get set up.

Once you know that, you can simply add the directive `After=<whatever>.target` to your custom service file, so systemd knows not to start it until after the prerequisite steps have completed.

If you can't track down what target specifically includes the `/sys` modules, you can always just guess at something that'll make your service load relatively late during boot, like `After=local-fs.target` for example. It's not the *most* correct way, but as long as you're careful not to introduce an "ordering cycle", it will probably work fine.